# Form authentication with jqgrid in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, forms-authentication, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using jqgrid, and on click of jqgrid it opens form on same page. 
I am also using ASP.Net user Authentication in it.

Problem is that, when i click grid row and session is expired. It open Login page in same form, instead of shifting to login page.

Can any one help me in this regard?

Here is my jqgrid code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(':checkbox').click(function () {
        var value = $("#cb").is(":checked");
        $("#document-grid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: function (postdata) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Calls/Documents.aspx/Find?showarchive=" + value,
                data: JSON.stringify($.extend({ 'filters': '' }, postdata)),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (res) {
                    $("#document-grid")[0].addJSONData(res.d);
                }
            });
        }
        }).trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true}]);
    });

    $("#document-grid").generalGrid({
        url: '/Calls/Documents.aspx/Find',
        jqGridOptions: {
            pager: '#document-grid-pager',
            colNames: ['Titel', 'Uploaddatum', 'Omschrijving', 'Bestandsnaam'],  //, 'Type' ],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'Titel', index: 'Title' },
                    { name: 'Uploaddatum', index: 'Uploaddatum', sorttype: 'date', searchoptions: {
                            dataInit: function (elem) {
                                $(elem).datepicker({
                                    onSelect: function(dateText, inst){ $("#document-grid")[0].triggerToolbar(); }
                                });
                            },
                        }
                    },
                    { name: 'Beschrijving', index: 'Description' },
                    { name: 'Bestandsnaam', index: 'Filename' }
            //                    { name: 'Type', index: 'Type' }
                ],
            sortname: 'UploadDate',
            caption: '',
            onSelectRow: function (Id) {
                alert(Id);
                $("#document-form").box('destroy').ajaxFormPanel('destroy').ajaxFormPanel({ url: '/Forms/Document.aspx?Id=' + Id,
                    loaded: function (s) {
                        $("#txtUploadDate, #txtExpirationDate", s.element).datepicker();
                        $(s.element).box({ title: 'Document bewerken' });
                    },
                    postback: function (s) {
                        $("#document-grid").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true}]);
                        // $("#document-form").ajaxFormPanel('destroy').ajaxFormPanel({ url: '/Forms/Document.aspx?Edited=true&Id=' + Id }).ajaxFormPanel('open');                    
                    }
                }).ajaxFormPanel('open');
            }
        }
    });
```

and my user Authentication code in Web.config is:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
         protection="All"
         timeout="1"
         name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
         path="/"
         requireSSL="false"
         slidingExpiration="true"
         defaultUrl="Default.aspx"
         cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
         domain=""
         enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
</authentication>
```

Thanx in advance..

Answer (score 0):

i would imagine you could check the http response for a return code of 301 (redirected). something like

```
if (response.status == 301)
{
    document.location = "login.aspx";
    return;
}
load jqgrid normally.
```